# End / interrupt / switch one event by another event in managed C++ GUI

Tags: c++, winforms, events, visual-c++, parallel-processing

I will try to keep it as simple as possible. Let's assume we created the following, very simple GUI. It contains two buttons:

[image: Image of my GUI]
**UPDATE: I can post nice images! :)**
I created two static variables:

```
public: static int counter = 0;  // our output
public: static int action = 0;   // info about action status
```

After clicking the [START] button, the following code is triggered:

```
private: System::Void start_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    // Change the action value so it is visible in the form
    action = 1;

    std::string str_value;
    String^ managed_str_value;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {

        // Update the counter:
        counter = i;

        // I want to break the loop and print the value of 'counter'
        //in 'output_txt' textbox once I click the 'STOP' button
        if (action == 0) {

            // Conversion from int to managed string:
            std::ostringstream str_streamer;
            str_streamer << counter;
            str_value = str_streamer.str();
            managed_str_value = gcnew String(str_value.c_str());

            // Print in the textbox:
            this->output_txt->Text = managed_str_value;

            // Finish the loop:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, after clicking button [STOP], I just set the value of action to 0 like this:

```
private: System::Void stop_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    // On stop_btn click, I just switch action value to 0, which I expect 
    // to be noticed inside loop started by 'start_btn'
    action = 0;  
}
```

I got used to such event handling in some projects written in LabVIEW, which worked like a charm, but here, clicking [START] button makes me wait for the end of processing this simple loop and freezes the GUI for the time of computation, which - as a result - gives me no chance to stop it in the middle of processing (which is necessary).

Another question (which I think is related th this problem) is: Why after moving the code printing the result to output_txt (like below) I can't see every new value updated in my textbox?

```
private: System::Void start_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    // Change the action value so it is visible in the form
    action = 1;

    std::string str_value;
    String^ managed_str_value;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {

        // Update the counter:
        counter = i;

        // Now I try to print the result every time I switch the counter:
        std::ostringstream str_streamer;
        str_streamer << counter;
        str_value = str_streamer.str();
        managed_str_value = gcnew String(str_value.c_str());

        this->output_txt->Text = managed_str_value;

        // I want to break the loop once I click the 'STOP' button
        if (action == 0) {

            // Finish the loop:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The overall problem is much more complex, but this example is just as simple as it can be to keep the essence of the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Understanding the event-driven nature of UI programming is pretty essential.  The UI thread will not paint the textbox and will not detect the Stop button press while it is occupied by that large for() loop.  It can only do one thing at a time.  Long-running code needs to be executed by a worker thread, the BackgroundWorker and Task classes help you write that kind of code.

Comment: I think using BackgroundWorker should do that... It seems odd to add new thread just for the sake of not cluttering GUI by (even as simple as in this example) calculations. My thought was it is supposed to be managed by internal algorithms, but I was apparently wrong. As I am working on Windows Forms, any useful links or tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some research I used BackgroundWorker (available in Windows Forms tools list). Now it works like a charm. I post my solution to the problem so the others might benefit from it.

BackgroundWorker has three events defined:

```
    // Background Worker 
// What is being processed
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {

        for (int i = counter; i < 1000000; i++) {

            // Sleep to prevent stack overflow (I think)
            System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(10);

            // Update the counter:
            counter = i;

            // Reporting progress:
            backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(counter);

            // This happens when we trigger cancellation of work 
            // for Background Worker
            if (backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending) {
                 e->Cancel = true;
                 backgroundWorker1->ReportProgress(0);
                 return;
            }
        }
    // Final result
    e->Result = counter;
}

// How do we report progress
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {

        // Conversion from int to managed string:
        std::ostringstream str_streamer;
        str_streamer << e->ProgressPercentage;
        std::string str_value = str_streamer.str();
        String^ managed_str_value = gcnew String(str_value.c_str());

        // Display current status
        this->output_txt->Text = managed_str_value;
}

// What happens after work is done
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e) {
    if (e->Cancelled) {

        // Conversion from int to managed string
        std::ostringstream str_streamer;
        str_streamer << counter;
        std::string str_value = str_streamer.str();
        String^ managed_str_value = gcnew String(str_value.c_str());

        // Print current value
        this->output_txt->Text = managed_str_value;
    }
    else {
        this->output_txt->Text = e->Result->ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is what I do when I click my two buttons (Start / Stop):

```
// START button
private: System::Void start_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        if (!backgroundWorker1->IsBusy) {

            // Start the execution asynchronously
            backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else {
            this->output_txt->Text = "Busy processing, please wait";
        }
}

// STOP button
private: System::Void stop_btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    if (backgroundWorker1->IsBusy) {

        // Cancel work in progress
        backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
    }
    else {
        this->output_txt->Text = "No operation in progress";
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for the others. If anything seems not optimized (especially thread sleep), I would appreciate any tips or comments you have in mind after reading the code.